# Blazor - Nested component does not highlight invalid fields or display ValidationMessages

Tags: validation, components, blazor, validationmessage

I can't figure out how to highlight invalid fields and display individual ValidationMessages for **nested components**. The same code when added to the page works as expected, but when moved to a separate component the page's ValidationSummary displays errors for this component just fine, but component itself does not provide any validation results.

I did an extensive search and I only found topics about validation of complex models, but nothing about displaying validation information in nested components. This suggests that I am probably missing something simple, but I can't figure out what this is.

Here is the simplified code reproducing this behavior.

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Added On Date is required")]
    public DateTime? AddedOn { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildComponent.razor**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        @(new MarkupString(Caption))
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <input type="text" @bind-value=@TextValue />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => TextValue) />
        
        <input type="datetime-local" @bind-value=@DateValue />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => DateValue) />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
}
```

**TestPage.razor**

```
@page "/test"

<EditForm OnValidSubmit="HandleFormSubmit" Model="@ProductModel">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    @*ValidationMessages are returned/displayed*@
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Control on the Page
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="text" @bind-value=@ProductModel.Name />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => ProductModel.Name) />

            <input type="datetime-local" @bind-value=@ProductModel.AddedOn />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => ProductModel.AddedOn) />
        </div>
    </div>

    @*ValidationMessages are NOT returned/displayed*@
    <ChildComponent Caption="Nested Component"
                    DateValue=@ProductModel.AddedOn
                    TextValue=@ProductModel.Name />

    @*ValidationSummary displays errors as expected*@
    <ValidationSummary />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm>

@code {

    Product ProductModel = new Product();

    private async Task HandleFormSubmit(EditContext context) { }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using info from the [link](https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch) provided by @NeilW I am now able to change the CSS of input controls (red border when invalid, green when valid), but I am still not able to display ValidationMessages for invalid controls. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This should help you ... https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch/

Comment: @NeilW, thank you for the link! It did help, but only partially. I added the code and component control's now have valid/invalid CSS set on validation, which is a progress, but the ValidationMessages are still not displayed. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I do have the same problem! You can get the Blazor code and see how the standard ValidationMessage component works which is what I am hoping to do.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://chrissainty.com/creating-bespoke-input-components-for-blazor-from-scratch) & [this](https://chrissainty.com/creating-a-custom-validation-message-component-for-blazor-forms) articles from Chris Sainty provide the solution. Thanks to [@NeilW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936204) for sharing the link.

Here is the updated code that works as expected:

**Product.cs** (no changes)

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Added On Date is required")]
    public DateTime? AddedOn { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildComponent.razor**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        @(new MarkupString(Caption))
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <input type="text" class="@textFieldCss"
            value=@TextValue @oninput="HandleTextInput" />
        @foreach (var message in CascadedEditContext?.GetValidationMessages(textFieldId))
        {
            <div class="validation-message">@message</div>
        }

        <input type="datetime-local" class="@dateFieldCss"
            value=@DateValue @oninput="HandleDateInput" />
        @foreach (var message in CascadedEditContext.GetValidationMessages(dateFieldId))
        {
            <div class="validation-message">@message</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private FieldIdentifier textFieldId;
    private FieldIdentifier dateFieldId;

    private string textFieldCss => CascadedEditContext?.FieldCssClass(textFieldId) ?? "";
    private string dateFieldCss => CascadedEditContext?.FieldCssClass(dateFieldId) ?? "";

    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditContext CascadedEditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<DateTime?> DateValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<string>> TextValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DateTime?>> DateValueExpression { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        textFieldId = FieldIdentifier.Create(TextValueExpression);
        dateFieldId = FieldIdentifier.Create(DateValueExpression);
    }

    private async Task HandleTextInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        await TextValueChanged.InvokeAsync(args.Value.ToString());
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(textFieldId);
    }

    private async Task HandleDateInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        await DateValueChanged.InvokeAsync(args.Value == null
                ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(args.Value));
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(dateFieldId);
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string TextValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; }
}
```

**TestPage.razor** - notice `@bind-` added to the component's attributes.

```
@page "/test"

<EditForm Model="@ProductModel">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Control on the Page
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <input type="text" @bind-value=@ProductModel.Name />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => ProductModel.Name) />

            <input type="datetime-local" @bind-value=@ProductModel.AddedOn />
            <ValidationMessage For=@(() => ProductModel.AddedOn) />
        </div>
    </div>

    <ChildComponent Caption="Nested Component"
                    @bind-DateValue=@ProductModel.AddedOn
                    @bind-TextValue=@ProductModel.Name />

    <ValidationSummary />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    Product ProductModel = new Product();
}
```

**Result**

[image]